# Twitter like tweet subscriptions + sse with the subscribed tweets / scaling

Tags: redis, real-time, scaling, server-sent-events

I have a realtime service based on fastify (https://fastify.dev) + sse (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-sse-v2).

Each client establishes a connection to the realtime service (event stream).

The realtime services listen to Redis Pub/Sub and push the information to the client.

Now, my goal is to accomplish a Twitter-like implementation for projects instead of tweets.

If the user scrolls over the timeline, the visible tweets are being subscribed, and the tweets that are not visible are being unsubscribed in separate requests. Now, the user gets only the realtime information for the tweets that are subscribed.

I now want to implement the same approach for my use case, as this seems to be a good fit.

Instead of tweets in my application, the user works with projects. Based on the selection I only want to push the realtime information via SSE to the user, that is relevant.

So basically, I would like to subscribe / unsubscribe projects, and if a pub/sub message comes in for a specific project, the user should only get the message of the subscribed projects.

I am not asking for the specific implementation; I am more interested in the infrastructure / design.

If the user connects to the realtime service, I hold the selected projects in the memory. If the user unsubscribes the project, I remove it from the list of subscribed projects. If a redis message comes in, I check the incoming message belongs to the subscribed projects. If this is the case, I push the message to the user.

My concerns are now, what happens if the realtime service scales up? The app is now connected to realtime service A but my request for subscribing / unsubscribing a project could go to realtime service B. As the memory is not shared, this solution would not work in case of scaling.

I thought about using redis / dragonflydb and save this informaton centralised. But I am not sure about the Key. I would like to set a TTL to keep the redis clear, but I am not sure how long the user stays on the page. So, using Redis seems not quite suitable for this case. I also could leave out the TTL and clear the redis key on connection.close(). But I am not 100% sure how reliable that approach would be.

I also thought about using sticky sessions to ensure the client always works on the same instance of the realtime service. In this case I could work with the memory and could reduce complexity, avoiding redis here. But I am not 100% sure if sticky sessions are reliable.

Is there any other approach that should be used here?

Thanks.